# inbound-channel-adapter not scaling based on executor

Tags: spring-integration, threadpoolexecutor, executor

I have jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter polling 50 records.
I am trying to improve the performance by scaling pollerExecutor pool-size to 1-10, so that multiple thread can process 50 records each:

```
    <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="initial.ContactType.poller"
    query="${poller.ContactType.get}"
    max-rows="${poller.deliveryContactType.maxRow:50}"
    row-mapper="ContactTypePollerRowMapper"
    data-source="dataSource" channel="ContactTypeChannel">
    <int:poller  fixed-rate="3000" time-unit="MILLISECONDS" task-executor="pollerExecutor">
        <int:advice-chain>
            <ref bean="pollerLoggingAdvice"/>
            <ref bean="txAdvice"  />
        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
<task:executor id="pollerExecutor" pool-size="1-10"
    queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

I tested the time taken to process 100,000 records is same irrespective of the pool-size.

I did three rounds of tests with pool-size=1, pool-size=1-3 and pool-size=1-10 respectively, 
in all three tests 100,000 records took 1 hr each time.

I confirmed by checking the logs that pollerExecutor threads are not working parallely. 
pollerExecutor-1 process all 50 records before pollerExecutor-2 starts processing.

Why container/pollerExecutor is not working parallely?

Comment: A couple of possibilities: 1 - some synchronization downstream, 2 - the DB is applying a table lock. Take a thread dump to see what's happening.

Comment: See also my answer.

Comment: @Gary, No synchronization downstream- I confirm that. No DB table lock, since I have multiple JVM, and all JVMs are polling fine parallelly. However, one set of 50 records instead of 10 sets at a time..

Comment: See @ArtemBilan ‘s answer. The thread dump I suggested would have shown that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
/**
 * Set the capacity for the ThreadPoolExecutor's BlockingQueue.
 * Default is {@code Integer.MAX_VALUE}.
 * <p>Any positive value will lead to a LinkedBlockingQueue instance;
 * any other value will lead to a SynchronousQueue instance.
 * @see java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
 * @see java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue
 */
public void setQueueCapacity(int queueCapacity) {
```

So, if you specify `queue-capacity="0"`, then you end up with a `SynchronousQueue`, which cannot accept new parallel tasks because there is already one busy for processing those 50 records.

Try to have some reasonable `queue-capacity` to observe possible parallelism.

Comment: Thanks, tried with `queue-capacity="1000"` it stayed on `pollerExecutor-1` forever since 50 records were processing in less than `fixed-rate` i.e 3 seconds, later changed the `queue-capacity="1"` with reduced `fixed-rate="1000"` now I do see threads working togather.

Hence the question, **Is `fixed-rate="1000"` per Executor?** i.e all 10 Executor will poll at the fixed-rate?

Comment: It seems we can't throttle the `fixed-rate`?